# Remove the selection from choice field in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a choice field in a custom list built using VS 2013. I'm able to select/unselect a value in the choice field while I add the new contents. But, while editing, I'm not able to unselect it. (Blank is not there while editing!). Do I need to add a blank to the records collection or is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: I think adding a blank line as a choice is what you need

Comment: I have added it and is working fine. But, one problem is .. When I add a new item, its showing two blanks in the choice. Its showing only 1 blank while editing, which is fine. Any way to avoid that ?

Comment: Can't reproduce youre problem, maybe double enter in youre choices?

Comment: I just added a blank before the choice data array in properties. While trying to add new item, the default blank and this new blank is showing. While editing, the default blank will not show. Hence, its showing only our blank. This is the situation. Hope you understood.